# C string problem

Tags: c

I made this function:

```
char** parse_cmd(const char* cmdline) {
    int i;
    int j = 0 ,k = 0;
    char ch[100][100];
    for(i=0; i<strlen(cmdline); i++) {
        if(cmdline[i] != ' ') {
            ch[j][k] = cmdline[i];
            k++;
        } else {
            j++;
            k = 0;
        }
    }

    return ch;
}
```

But when I compile the program I have this warning:

```
shell.c: In function ‘parse_cmd’:
shell.c:25:2: warning: return from incompatible pointer type
shell.c:25:2: warning: function returns address of local variable
```

Why?

Comment: Apart from anything else you can't return local arrays from functions like that, or indeed at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to return a pointer to a memory location that will not be associated with the array after the function returned. If you want to permanently allocate the memory, then you have to copy it with `malloc` (or any similar function) before returning it.

e.g:

```
char** parse_cmd(const char* cmdline) {
int i;
int j = 0 ,k = 0;
char **ch = (char**)malloc(100*100);
for(i=0; i<strlen(cmdline); i++) {
    if(cmdline[i] != ' ') {
        ch[j][k] = cmdline[i];
        k++;
    } else {
        j++;
        k = 0;
    }
}
return ch;
}
```

EDIT: fixed typo. Thanx

Comment: `char **ch` not `char ch**`. And you can't allocate a `char **` with one `malloc`.

Comment: You can, if you cast, but that seems like a hack, doesn' it? :/

Comment: No you can't. Dereferencing a `char **` gives a value of type `char *`. It expects to point somewhere. You need to a) allocate a `char (*)[100]`, b) do a loop to allocate each row, or c) change it to `char *` and manually index via multiplication, i.e. `ch[i * 100 + j]` instead of `ch[i][j]`.

Comment: Also you shouldn't cast the result of malloc in C.

Answer (score 3):

You're returning a pointer to memory that lives on the stack. Use heap allocated memory instead.

Answer (score 2):

The ch array is deallocated at the end of the function, that memory is stored on the stack which is invalid after the function returns. You should instead create a array in the calling function and pass the pointer into the parse_cmd() function.

Comment: +1 but it should also be noted that `char [N][O]` does not decay to `char **`, but to `char (*)[O]`.